# Inverse cosine of a complex number, take $\cos z=\sqrt{2}$ for $z$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

If I am given $\cos z=\sqrt{2}$ for $z$ and asked to solve it using the following: 
$$
\cos^{-1} z =-i \log\sqrt{z+i(1-z^2)}
$$

I've only gotten as far as taking $\cos z=\sqrt{2}$ and changing it to $z=\cos^{-1} \sqrt{2}$. from here I'm not sure how to plug into the formula. Am I using $z=x+iy$ or is $z=\sqrt{2}$??

Comment: Your confusion stems from the fact that you are using the same symbol $z$ for the argument of the cosine and its inverse.

Comment: Using different symbols for domain and range variables:  $w = \cos^{-1} z \Rightarrow \cos w = z$.

Comment: im not sure I follow. Im just trying to learn all this and it is overwhelming. Ive just learned arguments, and im barely grasping that, much less this type of problem. I guess I need to do a lot more reading onthis

Comment: When I write "the argument of a function" I just mean the input:  the $z$ in $ f(z)$.

Comment: For what it's worth, the formula is wrong. Try plugging in $1/2$: $$\cos^{-1}\left(\frac12\right) \stackrel?=-i \log\sqrt{\frac12+i\left(1-\left(\frac12\right)^2\right)}.$$ The left side is a real number, but the right side isn't.

Answer (score 1):

As log(x) is the natural logarithm, we get:

Real solution:

$$z=1$$

Complex solution:

$$z=(\frac{4}{51}-\frac{i}{51})((-2-5i)+(\frac{33+8i}{(((295-88i)+6((1380-2154i)^{\frac{1}{2}}))^{\frac{1}{3}}))})+(((295-88i)+6((1380-2154i)^{\frac{1}{2}}))^{\frac{1}{3}}))$$